# Scroll text to the left inside the TextBox automatically as the entered text reaches the right side of TextBox. C#, WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, textbox

I am working on a WPF application using MVVM, where users need to enter text from a TextBlock element into a TextBox. The TextBox's placeholder is "filled" and positioned directly above the TextBlock. It has a transparent background. As the user enters text, they reach the right side of the TextBlock, and the next words become hidden.

I want the TextBox to scroll automatically, so the last entered characters are visible on the left side of the TextBox, allowing the user to see what they need to enter next.

Here's the XAML code I am using:

```
<ScrollViewer
                x:Name="scroll"
                Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                CanContentScroll="True"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Border
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Background="#8EABAF">
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="tblTextToType"
                            Margin="2,0,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            AllowDrop="False"
                            FontFamily="/Fonts/Nunito_Sans/#NunitoSans"
                            FontSize="28"
                            Foreground="Gray"
                            TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>

                    <TextBox
                        x:Name="tbTypedText"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        AllowDrop="False"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        FontFamily="/Fonts/Nunito_Sans/#NunitoSans"
                        FontSize="28"
                        Foreground="Black"
                        IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled="True"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        IsUndoEnabled="False"
                        MaxLines="1"
                        SelectionBrush="Green">
                    </TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Additionally, I have two commands bound to the application window to handle keystrokes. The entered text is programmatically added to the TextBox if it matches the TextBlock's content.

**The Type method performs the required effect with scrolling text, but only after the first time the text exceeds the width of the TextBox, and I need it to happen after each such exceeding**

C# code handling KeyDownCommand and KeyUpCommand commands:

```
public ICommand KeyDownCommand { get; private set; }
        private void ExecuteKeyDown(object? obj)
        {
            if (obj is KeyEventArgs e && _keyboardButtons.ContainsKey(e.Key))
            {
                Key key = (e.Key == Key.System) ? e.SystemKey : e.Key;
                _keyboardButtons[key].KeyGrid.Background = SecondColor;

                switch (key)
                {
                    case Key.LeftCtrl:
                    case Key.RightCtrl:
                    case Key.LWin:
                    case Key.RWin:
                    case Key.LeftAlt:
                    case Key.RightAlt:
                    case Key.Back:
                    case Key.Tab:
                    case Key.Enter:
                        return;

                    case Key.LeftShift:
                    case Key.RightShift:
                    case Key.CapsLock:
                        UpdateKeyboard();
                        return;

                    case Key.Space:
                        Type(' ');
                        return;

                    default:
                        Type(char.Parse(_keyboardButtons[key].Content.Text));
                        break;
                }

                return;
            }
        }
        public ICommand KeyUpCommand { get; private set; }
        private void ExecuteKeyUp(object? obj)
        {
            if (obj is KeyEventArgs e && _keyboardButtons.ContainsKey(e.Key))
            {
                _keyboardButtons[e.Key].KeyGrid.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                UpdateKeyboard();
            }
        }

private bool isTextWidthExceededViewport = false;
private void Type(char character)
        {
            if (_textBox.Text.Length < _textBlock.Text.Length)
            {
                char expectedCharacter = _textBlock.Text[_textBox.Text.Length];

                if (character == expectedCharacter)
                {
                    _textBox.Text += character;

                    correctlyTypedTextLength++;
                    _progressBar.Value++;


                    _textBox.Foreground = (correctlyTypedTextLength == _textBox.Text.Length)
                        ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
                        : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                    _textBox.Select(0, correctlyTypedTextLength);

                    var typeface = new Typeface(_textBox.FontFamily, _textBox.FontStyle, _textBox.FontWeight, _textBox.FontStretch);
                    var formattedText = new FormattedText(_textBox.Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, _textBox.FlowDirection, typeface, _textBox.FontSize, _textBox.Foreground);
                    var size = new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height);
                    if (size.Width + 20 > _scrollViewer.ViewportWidth && !isTextWidthExceededViewport)
                    {
                        _scrollViewer.ScrollToRightEnd();
                        isTextWidthExceededViewport = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Fails++;
                    _textBox.Foreground = Brushes.Red;

                    if (Properties.Settings.Default.ErrorSound)
                        System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
                }
            }
        }
```

I have also tried using other commands and custom TextBox elements to achieve automatic scrolling, but without success.

To summarise, my WPF application requires a text box to automatically scroll so that the last characters entered remain visible on the left side of the text box when the user's input exceeds the visible width of the TextBox.

I would appreciate any insights or solutions on how to achieve this automatic scrolling behavior. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows; when the text comes close to the end it will scroll to close to the start

```
var typeface = new Typeface(_textBox.FontFamily, _textBox.FontStyle, _textBox.FontWeight, _textBox.FontStretch);
var formattedText = new FormattedText(_textBox.Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, _textBox.FlowDirection, typeface, _textBox.FontSize, _textBox.Foreground);
var size = new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height);

if (size.Width - scroll.HorizontalOffset >= (scroll.ViewportWidth - 10))
{
    scroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scroll.HorizontalOffset + scroll.ViewportWidth -10);
}
```

To scroll to the end you can do `scroll.ScrollToRightEnd();`

or to keep the typed text always in the center of text box you can do

```
var typeface = new Typeface(tbTypedText.FontFamily, tbTypedText.FontStyle, tbTypedText.FontWeight, tbTypedText.FontStretch);
var formattedText = new FormattedText(tbTypedText.Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, tbTypedText.FlowDirection, typeface, tbTypedText.FontSize, tbTypedText.Foreground);
var size = new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height);
scroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(size.Width > 6 ? size.Width -100 : size.Width);
```

like this

```
private void Type(char character)
    {
        if (_textBox.Text.Length < _textBlock.Text.Length)
        {
            char expectedCharacter = _textBlock.Text[_textBox.Text.Length];

            if (character == expectedCharacter)
            {
                _textBox.Text += character;

                correctlyTypedTextLength++;
                _progressBar.Value++;


                _textBox.Foreground = (correctlyTypedTextLength == _textBox.Text.Length)
                    ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
                    : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                _textBox.Select(0, correctlyTypedTextLength);
                var typeface = new Typeface(_textBox.FontFamily, _textBox.FontStyle, _textBox.FontWeight, _textBox.FontStretch);
                var formattedText = new FormattedText(_textBox.Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, _textBox.FlowDirection, typeface, _textBox.FontSize, _textBox.Foreground);
                var size = new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height);

                if (size.Width - scroll.HorizontalOffset >= (scroll.ViewportWidth - 10))
                {
                    scroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scroll.HorizontalOffset + scroll.ViewportWidth -10);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Fails++;
                _textBox.Foreground = Brushes.Red;

                if (Properties.Settings.Default.ErrorSound)
                    System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This helps to keep scroll always at the right side, making currently entered text at  the left side, but I need it to happen if entered text reaches right side of the TextBox element

Comment: Do you want the text to always be in the center?

Comment: I have a TextBlock with text, the text in this element is placed in one line, but since this text is long, it goes beyond the screen. There is a TextBox where the user must enter the text that is inside the TextBlock. In the TextBox, the text can also be written only in one line, without hyphens. Therefore, horizontal scroll is required there. When the user reaches the end of the visible part of the TextBox, the scroll should not be performed by one text character, but so that the text that was on the right side is moved to the beginning to the left

Comment: If my request is imposiible to imlement in WPF, than making text always being in center is the most suitable thing

Comment: I updated the answer to be the way you want